# UITableView Navigation Controller Dynamic Detail

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller

Is it possible to have a navigational controller for a UITableView make a decision to show either of three detail view controllers based on various criteria.

To put it another way, when a user taps on a UITableView cell, I want to show a different detail view for different users.

Any help is much appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

in your TableViewController (wich needs to be embedded in a UINavigationController), in

```
tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:
```

you could determine wich detail view fits your criteria, and then push the  ViewController of your choice onto the Stack using

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:yourViewController animated:YES];
```